# How to reduce size of python/qml application after using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, qtquick2, cx-freeze

I do not why, but my exe version of my python+qml/qtQuick application takes on large size. All package has over 550 MB. (folder PySide6 under lib has 400 MB). I suppose there is a lot of useless items in PySide6 folder - how to eliminate it?
Another think is that on clean windows installation the exe cannot be started:
[image]